# Is it okay to use <meta> tag with itemprop="name" attribute?

Tags: html, meta, microdata

I have the following issue: Brand name on my product page is displayed as a picture, so I,m unable to use something like that

```
<span itemprop="name">${brandName}</span>
```

because brand name will be displayed twice in that case.

So, I decided to add meta-tag with brand name written as plain text tag so that user can't see it:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="${brandName}"/>
```

Is it a normal solution?

Comment: Why didn't you use the first display of the brand name for your itemprop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta tags would be the way to go!

> Sometimes, a web page has information that would be valuable to mark up, but the information can't be marked up because of the way it appears on the page. The information may be conveyed in an image (for example, an image used to represent a rating of 4 out of 5) or a Flash object (for example, the duration of a video clip), or it may be implied but not stated explicitly on the page (for example, the currency of a price).

[Schema Getting Started](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing)